# How to override the default model construction behavior in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I currently have a project where I am utilizing a custom library of business objects that we want to pass over-the-wire through WebAPI/WFC/etc as needed. One of the hurdles I am reaching is dealing with the deserialization of an object through WebAPI.

The objects themselves adhere to the Factory Pattern, and as such, don't have public parameterless constructors (they are marked protected) and use a Factory to create an instance of the object. There are several important reasons for doing this, but we would like to be able to use the objects without the need for intermediary classes/models to be created as well.

Because of this, when the model is being bound to, the WebAPI framework fails to create an instance of the object, citing the "no parameterless constructors" error. I need to find a way to be able to call the factory method and return the new object to either a formatter or binder (or something else which is a part of the deserialization process) somehow.

Is there a clear cut way (and documentation) on how to extend Web API to handle this situation without having to implement another framework on top of it? I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

**Edit:**
So I eneded up creating a new Model Binder and created the object through the factory class in BindModel(). By assigning the object to bindingContext.Model and then just manually deserializing the object, I was able to achieve what was needed, but I am not sure if its 100% the right way.

See below for my code:

```
Public Class FactoryModelBinder
    Implements IModelBinder

    Public Function MindModel(actionContext as HttpActionContext, bindingContext as ModelBindingContext) As Boolean Implements IModelBinder.BindModel

        Dim type = bindingModel.ModelType
        Dim attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(FactoryAttribute, False)

        If attributes.Length > 0 Then

            Dim factoryAttribute As FactoryAttribute = DirectCast(attributes(0), FactoryAttribute)

            bindingContext.Model = factoryAttribute.FactoryType.InvokeMember("Create", BindingFlags.InokveMethod Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)

            Dim data as FormDataCollection = New FormDataCollection(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
            Dim dict as NameValueCollection = data.ReadAsNameValueCollection()

            For Each item as String in dict.Keys

                Dim pi as PropertyInfo = bindingContext.Model.GetType().GetProperty(item)

                pi.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, dict(item), Nothing)

            Next

            Return True

        End If

        Return False

    End Function
```

This code relies upon a custom attribute (FactoryAttribute) which specifies in the object class, the Type of the Factory so it can be used to call the Create() method.

I appreciate any input on this.

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm afraid that you're going to be stuck creating an adapter class.  I don't think WebAPI is old enough yet to have the rich customization that comes with the older .NET tech.